# ActionView::MissingTemplate in Pages#home

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

When trying to view my project via http://localhost:3000/ I get the error message:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate in Pages#home

Showing D:/row/dev/basismysql/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #13 raised:

Missing partial layouts/header with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "D:/row/dev/basismysql/app/views"

Extracted source (around line #13):


<body>

  <%= render "layouts/header" %>
  <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
  <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
  <%= yield %>
```

As you can see I have added `<%= render "layouts/header" %>` to application.html.erb. 
I created a file /views/layouts/header.html.erb. 
And under assets/stylesheets/header.css.scss I have also included a stylesheet for header.html.erb.

Changing line 13 to `<%= render "layouts/header" %>` made no difference.
Any ideas what is going wrong?

I'm using Rails 3.2.12, Ruby 4, MySQL and a Windows machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the HTML file for views/layouts/header.html.erb needs to be renamed. A partial needs an _ in front of the filename.

Rename the file to _header.html.erb and you should be good to go

Answer (score 0):

your header should be a partial. Rename

```
views/layouts/header.html.erb
```

to

```
/views/layouts/_header.html.erb
```